# CA certificate misses CA basicConstraint

Tags: openssl, certificates, ipsec

I am trying to create a self signed CA by doing the following:

```
ipsec pki --issue --cacert selfCA.pem --cakey ecdsaKEY.pem --ca --dn "..." --flag ikeintermediate --flag serverAuth --outform pem > cert.pem
```

but the terminal keeps telling me it misses CA basic constraint

I've searched the whole internet still can't resolve this issue.
 
Can anyone help?

(kali linux from UTM VM in m1 air mac)

Comment: ive actually added --ca in @ the first self signed cert and  now it worked! Thanks a lot gareth, extremely helpful comment , ive been trying for like 5-6 hours <3

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the CA which is signing your certificate does not have the Basic Constraint extension.

You need to first rebuild the self-signed root CA with the `--ca` option on the command line, to enable that extension.